# what does this mean "type ant 1>/dev/null"?

Tags: unix

I am probe in Unix.

I want to know what does this mean?

```
type ant 1>/dev/null
moduledir=`dirname $0`
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` command (under UNIX, don't confuse this with MS-DOS/Windows' `CMD.EXE`) will show you how a command would be interpreted if executed.

Using `type` that way, would print an error message (e.g. `ant not found`) should the `ant` command not be found/executable. As others have said, the `1>/dev/null` (or simply `>/dev/null`) redirects messages written to the standard output by that command to "nowhere", i.e. they will not be printed on the terminal / console. Messages written to the standard error stream would/will still occur. It looks like, that line was meant to check for whether `ant` could be executed/found, however a respective check to (say) abort the script was not provided, it could like this (depending on your shell, but it looks like a bourne shell flavor anyway):

```
 type ant > /dev/null
 [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
```

Another note: with `bash` the type command never writes any output to the standard error stream, i.e. even the message `... not found` gets written to standard output. So the command, as it stands, does never output anything, even in the case of an error (in which the message seems sensible to display, given that this fragment is used as a check anyway).

Finally, the

```
 moduledir=`dirname $0`
```

line stores the directory name of the currently executing script in the variable `moduledir`. You could later reference it like `$moduledir`, for example: `echo "The directory is: $moduledir`.

Frankly, the two statements, isolated as they are in your question make little sense. While syntax-wise correct, they bear no deeper meaning so one can only speculate what they were ment for. You might want to consider asking another question about what you are actually trying to achieve, rather than just posting (arbitrary) syntax.

Comment: Christian.K thank you~ I think I understood a little bit....but thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`1>/dev/null` in the first line, redirects `STDOUT`(Standard Output) to `/dev/null`. That means only **errors** (if exist) will be displayed on screen after running `type ant` command.

The second line sets `moduledir` variable to the output of `dirname $0` command which `$0` is the executed file name.

---

[`type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_(Unix)) basically tells you the type of it's argument. In your case it outputs the path of `ant` like this: `ant is /usr/bin/ant`

`>` is for stream redirection. and `1>` redirects standard output.

Read more about standard streams [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

finally `type ant 1>/dev/null` should output nothing if everything is fine.

Comment: Hi fardjad, thanks for your answer. But could think me as a person who just heard the name Unix. By the way I have to do this because I have to release a jar form git repo. Maybe I have to study some basic knowledge about Unix. Thank you all the same.